# Setting Visual C++ Studio/Express to strict ANSI mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ansi-c

I generally program & compile under Linux with gcc and -ansi flag; but I've been forced with doing a job in Visual C++ and whenever I compile my C code I get all the Microsoft warnings like

> 'fscanf': This function or variable
>   may be unsafe. Consider using fscanf_s
>   instead.

I get these despite following some steps on MSDN Developer's site for setting up an ANSI C project, but all the _s ("secure") calls are not ANSI C!

Any suggestions on putting Visual C++ Studio in a strict ANSI-only mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to suppress specific warnings is to add something like the following to the source.

```
#if defined( _WIN32 )
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in another answer, `#define`'ing `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING` will address the specific warnings you mentioned in your question.

If you're really looking for an ANSI-only mode, the closest thing is the [`/Za` compiler switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx).  Inside the Visual Studio IDE, you can find it in the project's Properties dialog (under **Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Language | Disable Language Extensions**).

Note that virtually all Windows apps build with Microsoft's compiler extensions enabled; e.g., I don't think you'd even be able to consume Windows SDK headers with `/Za` set.  If your code truly is strict ANSI, you should be OK.  If you have a few Windows-specific pieces in a project that is mostly strict ANSI, you could probably isolate those sources and only build those indivudal source files with `/Za` unset.

Comment: You are correct: `<windows.h>` and the `/Za` compiler switch hate each other. [Link to Microsoft Connect - Bug is *Closed*](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780509/including-windows-h-and-compiling-with-za-disable-language-extensions).

Answer (score 4):

These warnings can be suppressed by defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING`

Go to Procect Settings -> Preprocessor and add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING`

This isn't forcing compiler to comply with ANSI. Just suppresses use ..._s warnings